# ¿Cómo crear una cadena de texto con separadores eficientemente?

Tags: algoritmos, lenguaje-agnóstico, loops, condiciones

Esta pregunta es para compartir un truco muy simple que aprendí en StackOverflow y que ha servido para limpiar miles de casos en mi codigo.

> **NOTA:** no es una traducción, es simplemente una transmisión de conocimiento que creo necesaria e interesante y creada originalmente por mi para SO en Castellano.

---

Todos hemos montado una cadena de texto a mano insertando los separadores, por ejemplo:

- Caracteristicas de un elemento (coche) separadas por coma `,`

  ```
  ABS, ESP, EE, CC
  ```
- Listado para imprimir con saltos de linea `\n`

  ```
  producto1   2,23\n
  producto2   3,23\n
  producto33  5,31\n
  ```

Y nos hemos encontrado con uno de los siguientes problemas:

- insertar una comparativa a cada iteracion:

  **JAVA**

  ```
  // bucle que inserta valor v en variable x
  if ("".equals(x)) x = v;
  else              x = "," + v;
  ```

  **JAVASCRIPT**

  ```
  // bucle que inserta valor v en variable x
  if (x == "") x = v;
  else         x = "," + v;
  ```
- si no insertamos esa comparativa para optimizar, igualmente la tenemos que realizar posteriormente para evitar

  - ultimo elemento vacio:

    ```
    1,1,1,1,1,
    //       ↑ aquí!
    ```
  - primer elemento vacio

    ```
      ,1,1,1,1,1
    //↑ aquí!
    ```

---

## PREGUNTA

¿Hay algún patrón para evitar este usual y molesto caso y que cumpla con las siguientes características?

- Transversal (usable en cualquier lenguaje).
- Óptimo (evitar funciones/metodos costosos, comparaciones o iteraciones extras)
- Legible

Comment: Creo que el párrafo inicial no es necesario. Quien vea esto dentro de dos años no estará familiarizado con la polémica :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu la verdad es que yo tampoco, pero tal y como está el tema, creo adecuado ponerla y eliminarla mas adelante.

Comment: hecho @rnrneverdies ademas he añadido algunos ejemplos prácticos, gracias!!!!

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Qué problema hay con añadir la comparación al bucle?

Comment: Lo de *transversal* habría que aclararlo mejor, porque este problema no se plantea en lenguajes que usan colecciones, sobre todo en lenguajes funcionales.

Comment: Chema, que tiene que ver una coleccion con un asunto tan basico? Usarlas en cualquiera d los ejemplos es ineficaz

Comment: @Darkhogg problema no hay, pero no es eficiente y baja el rendimiento en la mayoria de los casos.

Comment: @JordiCastilla ¿Por qué no es eficiente? Si en lugar de llamar a `.equals` usas un booleano para discriminar la primera iteración de las demás, la comparación es constante. Eso sumado al predictor de saltos prácticamente eliminan el condicional. Habría que hacer un benchmark, pero dudo que realmente sea ineficiente.

Comment: la primera comparación lo hace menos eficiente, de la misma manera que el predictor de saltos *intenta* adivinar el próximo valor del condicional en la iteración, la JVM solo asigna la variable 1 vez por muchas vueltas que de el loop.... Pero benchmarkea y comparte. Me parece una discusión muy interesante :)

Comment: @JordiCastilla Pues... http://jsperf.com/es-so-string-joining-speed

Comment: @Darkhogg acabas de demostrar que javascript es ultra dependiente del navegador con el que se ejecuta que es el que crea la optimización obteniendo un mejor resultado en cada caso ¿Hay algo que puedas aportar concluyente?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Sí: Que no hay una respuesta. Si te sirve de algo, con Python he obtenido el mismo resultado y, obviamente, con Node también lo obtendría (ya que usa el mismo runtime que Chrom*). Lo ideal sería probarlo con un lenguaje nativo (C/C++) con y sin optimizaciones.

Comment: hoy no tengo tiempo, pero intentare hacer el benchmark en java y c++ y colgare mis resultados junto a los tuyos. Muchas grácias!

Comment: @JordiCastilla Lo ineficaz es estar comprobando en cada iteración si la cadena está vacía. Los compiladores de lenguajes funcionales aprovechan mejor el polimorfismo para usar la mejor función según si la lista está vacía o no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente hay un truco muy sencillo y eficaz que hace que las cadenas creadas de esta manera se monten perfectamente optimizando al maximo el codigo:

- **Crear una variable `SEPARADOR` vacia al principio y que asignas al final de cada iteracion:**

**JAVA SIN USAR LA TECNICA**

```
final String SEPARADOR = ",";
StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder("");
for (String s : listaDeStrings) {   
    if (cadena.equals("")) {
        cadena.append(s);
    } else {
        cadena.append(SEPARADOR);
        cadena.append(s);
    }
}
```

**JAVA**

```
String SEPARADOR = "";
StringBuilder cadena= new StringBuilder();
for (String s : listaDeStrings) {   
    cadena.append(SEPARADOR);
    cadena.append(s);
    SEPARADOR = ",";
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY SIN USAR LA TECNICA**

```
var separador = ",";
var cadena= "";

$('.datos').each(function(index, value) {
    if (cadena === "") {
        cadena += separador + value.value;
    } else {
        cadena += separador + value.value;
        separador = ",";
    }
});
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
var separador = "";
var cadena = "";

$('.datos').each(function(index, value) {
    cadena += separador + value.value;
    separador = ",";
});
```

Ahi queda para quien quiera usarlo.

- Mejora mucho visualmente la claridad y legibilidad
- Mejora enormemente el rendimiento
- Facilita la integridad de datos.

Comment: Esta muy bueno el aporte :), solo falta responder el tema de que sea transversal, ¿como se haría esto transversal?. Saludos!

Comment: Creo que los bucles, la concatenacion y la asignacion son transversales a todos los lenguages de programacion. O te refieres a plantear la solucion en pseudocodigo?

Comment: Entiendo, pensé que te referías a transversal en cuanto a arquitectura de la solución, de no ser así pues esta bien tu respuesta :)

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres, puedes ampliar?

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, esta solución es muchísimo menos clara que la original.  Tampoco es necesariamente óptima, dependiendo del caso y del lenguaje, aunque este punto es bastante dificil de incumplir.

Comment: ¿Por qué una asignación es más óptima que un if? Eso puede variar dependiendo del lenguaje.

Comment: En cuanto a transversal pensé que se refería a dividirlo en módulos/capas, donde ese método estaría en la modulo/capa de utilidades, y recibiría como parámetro el elemento a procesar, por esta razón digo que el código actual no cumplía en ese sentido de ser transversal, **Tener en cuenta** que esto también depende del lenguaje y/o contexto de la solución.

Answer (score 4):

#### Esta es otra forma de encararlo.

En casos donde se trabaja con items, y se los va agregando, lo ideal es usar un **[array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)**.

Y a partir de ahí:

1. `array.push()` agrega un elemento en el array
2. `array.join()` concatena todos los elementos con un separador

#### Código

```js
var separador = ',';
var items = []; //array vacío

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // agrega 1 elemento al array
    items.push(i);
}

//concatena con separador
var arrayManual = items.join(separador)

// mostrar el resultado
resultado.innerText = arrayManual;
```

```html
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Comment: Mariano la pregunta y respuesta son para casos, en los cuales estoy seguro te has encontrado muchas veces, en que no tienes posibilidad de usar arrays. Ademas, creo que estaras de acuerdo conmigo que, aunque tu solucion hace lo que tiene que hacer, no es precisamente **a) legible b) optima**  (por el elevado uso de objetos y funciones internas) ni **c) transversal**  (puede ser aplicada a cualquier lenguaje). Como se pretende en la pregunta original. Ademas ten en cuenta que has omitido el tag java

Comment: @Mariano ¿Cómo has hecho lo del fragmento de código ejecutable?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @astrojuanlu tambien tienes un boton donde aparece un wizard como jsfiddle que permite hacerlo muy facil

Comment: @Jordi Quizás la pregunta debería haber mostrado un caso específico en el que no se pueden usar arrays. Justamente concatenar sobre un string de esa forma es algo que jamás haría, y por eso la alternativa planteada.

Comment: realmente, los casos mostrados son concatenaciones de string con separador, pero no se convierten a array por lo que tu suposicion no deja de ser eso, una suposición. Ademas, te sigues saltando lo de la solucion transversal y sigues omitiendo el tag java, simplemente sales del paso para un ejemplo concreto y no das un patron a seguir que es lo que se pide en la pregunta desde el inicio

Comment: Y para que no quede ninguna duda, he eliminado todas las ocurrencias de la palabra array.

Comment: @astrojuanlu Es el 7mo botón cuando editás una publicación. No estaban activados [pero los habilitaron ayer](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/68/127)

Comment: @JordiCastilla por que tiene que cumplir todos los tags, a mi me parece que esta mal tageada la pregunta.

Comment: sobre lo de *concatenar sobre un string de esa forma es algo que jamás haría*, explicame como harias (por ejemplo) una enumeracion de productos y cantidades separadas por comas para una factura? Y cuando  `SEPARADOR = \n`???

Comment: *encontrable* ???

Comment: y *SI* es obligatorio cumplir los tags, para clarificar tambien he eliminado los de lenguajes concretos y añadido multi-lenguaje

Comment: @rnrneverdies estoy de acuerdo contigo.  A ver que te parece el nuevo :)

Answer (score 4):

No existe ningún método óptimo que sirva para todos los lenguajes. Incluso dentro del mismo lenguaje, el método óptimo puede variar dependiendo de la estructura de datos donde estén los datos a concatenar.

Para el 99% de los programas, que el código sea legible es más importante que optimizarlo. Hazlo legible primero, y optimiza después sólo si compruebas que es necesario.

- Si el lenguaje tiene alguna función que haga esto, utilízala. Es lo más legible y normalmente lo más óptimo. Por ejemplo, en javascript usa `Array.join` si los datos están en un array.
- Si no, simplemente hazlo legible y no te preocupes por ahora de optimizarlo. Un `if` en el bucle es legible, una variable al principio vacía que se actualiza en el bucle como propone Jordi Castilla en su respuesta también. Preferir un método u otro depende de cada programador.

Si después de implementarlo compruebas que necesitas mejorar el rendimiento, una posible opción, si la forma de recorrer los datos lo permite, es sacar la primera iteración fuera del bucle. Por ejemplo:

```
List<String> listaConDatos = obtenerDatos();
StringBuffer resultado = new StringBuffer();
String separador = ",";

Iterator<String> it = listaConDatos.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
  resultado.append(it.next());
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    resultado.append(separador);
    resultado.append(it.next());
  }
}
```

El problema es que esto es claramente menos legible, y no todas las formas de recorrer los datos permiten hacerlo.

Comment: El método óptimo de cada lenguaje también puede variar dependiendo del uso que se necesite. Por ejemplo, el uso de StringBuffer con threads no es recomendado porque esta clase no es thread-safe. En ese caso es mejor usar StringBuilder

Comment: @JhonAlx es al revés: `StringBuilder` no es thread safe, mientras que `StringBuffer` sí puesto que todos sus métodos son sincronizados.

Answer (score 2):

Las otras respuestas comparan con una cadena vacía. No entiendo si eso es parte de la definición del problema. Si no lo es, lo siguiente es mi solución.

Suelo usar una variable `boolean`. Algo como:

```
boolean primerElemento = false;
for (/* ... */) {
   if (primerElemento) {
      primerElemento = false;
   } else {
      buffer.append(",");
   }
   buffer.append(siguenteElemento);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Demasiadas vueltas. Lo menos costoso es hacer trim de la coma al final.

Eso es todo, entre mas grande el monto de datos cualquier validación 1 a 1 se vuelve demasiado costosa, y es precisamente en ese caso cuando se necesita que sea optimo.

Borra la coma del final. Una única operación una única vez por fila. FiN

Ahora ese es el menor de los problemas algunos de los  demos java y js que te han mostrado la ineficiencia es la regla... Puedes hacer cosas mucho mas óptimas con C# o C, C++... Pero bueno pediste algo agnóstico. Ahí lo tienes .

Answer (score 0):

En JAVA 8 lo podemos hacer tal que así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"Hola", "David"};
    System.out.println(concat(array));
}
public static String concat(String... strs) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for (String str : strs) {
        joiner.add(str);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

El resultado será: Hola, David

Fijarse que el resultado no incluye ninguna ', ' detrás de David.